# Has anyone performed 8 perfect Faro shuffles in a row?

Tags: tricks

8 perfect Faro shuffles in a row will return a deck of cards to the original order. I am curious as to whether anyone has actually performed this feat. I found a [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7lNk7bfkFq8) video, but does anyone have any more definite proof of whether this feat has been accomplished?

Comment: I take it you believe that video you linked to is fake? In principle I see no impossibility in doing 8 "Out Faro" shuffles to return the deck to its original order. I'm pretty sure a lot of professional card magicians could do it. Alex Elmsley has published a lot about the Faro shuffle, including the underlying mathematics.

Comment: @Oliver: I don't believe that it is fake, I'm just being skeptical =P

Comment: In the comments to video, the poster admitted there are a few tricks to increase the rate of success. One such is the use an ordered deck, he can always split the two cards perfectly just by remembering the middle cards. While the feat still requires a lot of practice (as all hand tricks do) and the right type of cards (e.g. plastic, not paper cards); I don't think there is any need to be skeptical if someone have actually done it and made a video about it. Is it difficult, yes; is it impossible, definitely not, as long as you know a few tricks and are good with your hands.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Quite a few more than eight actually:

> British magician David Willmott completed 2,784 ‘Faro’ shuffles at Illusions Magic Bar in Bristol - setting the new world record for the most complete perfect Faro shuffle cycles in 12 hours.

Source:   [World Records Academy](http://www.worldrecordsacademy.org/stunts/most_perfect_Faro_shuffle_cycles_world_record_set_by_David_Willmott_101636.htm)

Answer (score 4):

In short Yes!
I recommend the book *Magic Tricks, Card Shuffling, and Dynamic Computer Memories* by [Ivars Peterson](http://www.maa.org/mathland/mathtrek_8_3_98.html) where he explains how to do it, and the maths (if you are interested, as a skeptic ;) behind it).